# Billing Country populated during Data Migration when source was blank

Tags: data-loader, account, migration, data-migration, address

I have migrated a sample account with only 2 fields account name and billing street.
However upon migration the country value is populated as united states.
I have used data loader and the allow null value option is checked in settings.

Why is the country value being populated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess one of our triggers/workflows populated this.
please check your system :)

Comment: No workflows or triggers. Its a new org

Comment: Is default value set?

Comment: How Do I check if it is a default value. Because the all the fields in Billing address is one field in setup

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The list can be managed from State and Country Picklist from Data Management.
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_state_country_picklists_overview.htm&language=en_US